# How to build openModelica project with cmake-gui?

Tags: openmodelica

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uALtg.png)

I tried to build pthreas and generate pthreadsConfig.cmake,but it doesn't work in openmodelica project?

I have tried to build pthread4w with cmake because of lacking it when I building openmodelica project?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69oEY.png)

Comment: Please don't add the console output as images, but as text. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I'm assuming you are trying to compile OpenModelica from source on a Windows 10 machine.

Unless you specifically want to compile OpenModelica with the Windows compiler toolchain I would suggest to follow the [OpenModelica README.Windows.md](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/OMCompiler/README.Windows.md#windows-instructions) on how to build with CMake and MSYS with the GNU tool-chain.

On Windows the [OMDev package](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/OMCompiler/README.Windows.md#1-omdev-package) is used to provide Linux-like compiler toolchains and has all needed dependencies including a MSYS environment and pthreads.

If you really want to compile with a Windows C/C++ compiler toolcahin, e.g. MSVC you can try it with CMake, but we don't test this on the OpenModelica CI and it will probably fail with some minor problem. The other way is to use the "old" Makefiles and compile the msvc target `simulationruntimecmsvc`. At least that is tested in the CI. But I wouldn't recommend this way.

---

Also you might want to ask the developers of OpenModelica directly on GitHub: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/discussions